# Error sending email with attachments with mailgun (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mailgun

I'm trying to send an email with an autogenerated pdf file as attachment using MailGun, but I get an error from the requests library. It's driving me crazy as I am using exactly the same code as in the examples.

I get this error:  List object has no attribute 'update'

This is my code:

```
# Generation of the pdf file        
pdf = StringIO.StringIO()
pisa.CreatePDF("<Some html code>", dest=pdf, encoding='utf8')

# Sending the email

requests.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<MY_DOMAIN>/messages",
        auth=("api", "<MY_API_KEY>"),
        files = [("attachment", pdf.getvalue())],
        data={"from": "sender@email.com",
              "to": ["Jhon Doe", "destiny@email.com"],
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Trying to send an attachment!"})
```

If I remove the files line it works, but I need to send the attachment.
I've tried changing the kind of file I send. I've also tried something more simple:

```
files = [("attachment", "Bla, bla bla")]
```

but the error I get is about the format (list) of that line.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

The post parameter "files" must be a dict!

Try this:

```
# Generation of the pdf file        
pdf = StringIO.StringIO()
pisa.CreatePDF("<Some html code>", dest=pdf, encoding='utf8')

# Sending the email
requests.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<MY_DOMAIN>/messages",
        auth=("api", "<MY_API_KEY>"),
        files={"attachment": pdf.getvalue()},
        data={"from": "sender@email.com",
              "to": ["Jhon Doe", "destiny@email.com"],
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Trying to send an attachment!"})
```

More infos about uploading files with the *requests* library can be found here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: Thanks. I was sure I tried this solution, but it seems I didn't.  Now I've tried again and it works.